# EWS FolderPermission Add

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

How do you add multiple user folder permissions to a single folder in EWS? Without them being reset? So if i wanted to give `usera@domain.com` and `userb@domain.com` permissions to one folder at once?

```
UserId user = new UserId();
user.PrimarySmtpAddress ="userabc@domain.com";
FolderPermission fldperm = new FolderPermission(user, FolderPermissionLevel.Editor);
strfolder.Permissions.Add(fldperm);
strfolder.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the [FolderPermissionCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.folderpermissioncollection%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). Add all permissions to that collection then use the AddRange property to add the FolderPermissionCollection.

Thanks 
Niall